# Cant see Mysql data source at the add connect to database

Tags: asp.net-4.0, mysql-connector, visual-web-developer-2010

I have visual web developer 2010 express and mysql/connector 6.4.3
When I press on the database explorer tab -> connect to database, I need to choose data source but I dont see mysql data source as I shold.
I've tried to reinstall it..
I have both visual studio 2008 and visual web developer 2010 express.

Btw, during the mysql/connector I only saw that he configured vs2008..

How can I fix that?

p.s.
I saw [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?47,410389,410403#msg-410403) that its not supported, is it true??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old, but to answer your question I was having the same issue until I tried it on the ultimate version. It picks it right up. You just need to re-install the connector.

So short answer, yes. :(